# Python: how to define a class that behaves like a function?

Tags: python, function, class

I would like to define in python a class that behaves like a function with additional attributes. In particular, it should be seamlessly applied to a variable.

Let’s try to explain with a mathematical example. Say I am very much into sinusoïdal functions, but also interested by their *frequency*. A function x -> sin(omega x) has the attribute *frequency*, namely the value of omega. It can also be applied to a float x.

I can write:

```
from numpy import sin, pi

class SinFunc:
    def __init__(self, omega):
        self.frequency = omega

    def apply_to(self, x):
        return sin(self.frequency * x)
```

I could then play with a sinusoïdal function:

```
MySinFunc = SinFunc(3)
print(MySinFunc.frequency)
print(MySinFunc.apply_to(pi)) 
# output
# 3
# 0 (almost!)
```

But what I would like is to be able to write directly `MySinFunc(pi)`, with the attribute *frequency* still defined.

How to achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make an object callable, you need to add a `__call__` class method that will handle the call.

Rename your `apply_to` function to `__call__` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problem!